# More advanced android facebook example

Tags: android, facebook

I'm having some problems with facebook integration on my android app. I've looked at the examples that come with the api and i can do the things shown in those ok. But i'm having problems with other things such as getting single sign on to work properly, authentication across multiple activities in the app and loading a facebook page (non-api call) without being asked to log in again.

Anyone have examples that show these?

Comment: most of us do not simply want to post our own, hard worked code. Be sure to post what you have and we can help you debug.

Answer (score 0):

When making API calls, you usually need to include the `access_token` parameter that was issued when the user authenticated. This is how facebook knows who you are when you make requests.

Similarly, when loading facebook pages (not using the API), you have to remember to send the cookies Facebook sent when the user logged in. Normally the browser keeps track of these automatically, but in your program or app you might have to handle them manually.

I don't have experience with Android specifically, and I don't know what you're using to load and render facebook pages, but knowing how facebook is keeping track of logged-in users should give you an idea of where to start. A [google search](http://www.google.com/webhp?q=android%20api%20cookie%20handling) or two should get you on your way.

Answer (score 0):

Go to facebook.java class and change package name com.facebook.katana to com.facebook.katanaaa or any one of your own choice. This worked for me .